# fstab mounting not working with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mount, 20.04, fstab

Having a fresh install of 20.04 along with cifs-utils, I tried to reuse my fstab that I ported over from 18.04. the manual mount command that I wanted to reuse looks like this

```
//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/user/myuser /media/HomeM cifs auto,uid=1000,gid=1000,credentials=/home/myname/.secure/.credentials,vers=1.0
```

and the credentials file in the respective location reads

```
username=myusername
password=mysecurepassword
```

However, upon invoking

```
sudo mount -av
```

I get

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX,unc=\\XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\user,vers=1.0,uid=1000,gid=1000,user=myusername,prefixpath=myusername,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

It used to work a week ago with Ubuntu 18.04

any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install keyutils as well to make it work on 20.04. I found this question on the same quest and came back to answer now that I figured it out. This is the top google result.